# Periodic update happens only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery script

```
<script>
(function worker() {
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/course.json',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#current').text(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
      // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
      setTimeout(worker, 1000);
    }
  });
})();
</script>
```

This works only once. After one update, even if ajax response changes, value of `#current` does not change.

If this problem is related to changing DOM properties, I don't know how I use `.delegate` here there is no actual event like `click`, etc.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi yes, `$.ajax` has a `complete` callback.

Comment: @Hamms Thank you.

Comment: Please test this: `complete: function(response)` and this: `setTimeout(function(){worker();}, 1000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `console.log(data);` line inside your success callback and check that the data has truly changed. Also go to F12 Network tab and check that the response is actually a 200 instead of cached one (302 and such). Maybe the problems are caches. You have to return no-cache headers with your file or add a random get parameter to invalidate cache.

Also, why don't you add the timeout inside the success callback? Is weird to have 2 callbacks with the same purpose. Just to be sure that the callback is called.

Comment: I can see that response is different watching request results in Chrome Network mode

Comment: Do the console.log(data) thing.

Comment: For some reason removing complete resolved the issue